Compartir Spreadsheet con script con otros usuarios de mi Workspace
Tengo una Spreadsheet con unos scripts que se ejecutan al darle click a una nueva opción en la barra de menús.
Al ser el editor del script, se me ejecuta perfectamente.
He añadido a la hoja como Editores a otros usuarios de mi Workspace y pueden abrir la hoja, pero no se ejecuta ningún script, ni siquiera el de onload que muestra la nueva opción.
Supongo que tengo que hacer algo más, pero no se que puede ser.
¿Alguien me puede indicar que pasos me faltan para compartir el spreadsheet con los scripts funcionando?
Lo primero que detecté es que teníanm que ser editores de la hoja para poder acceder a los scripts,  pero veo que no es suficiente. He googleado pero no encuentro lo que me falta hacer.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Los editores de la hoja de cálculo deberían poder ejecutar el script contenido en la misma con algunas condiciones y limitaciones. Esto está explicado en la documentación https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/overview. Para lo básico sobre scripts para hoja de cálculo puedes ir directamente a https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/guides/sheets y sobre la solución de problemas puedes ir directamente a https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting.
En relación a la mención de "onload" este no se menciona entre los activadores simples (ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/guides/triggers).
